# Get element from array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
array (size=1)
  29 => 
    object(stdClass)[300]
      public 'term_id' => string '29' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'Advertisement' (length=13)
      public 'slug' => string 'advertisement' (length=13)
      public 'term_group' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => string '32' (length=2)
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'wp_portfolio_categories' (length=23)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => string '27' (length=2)
      public 'count' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'object_id' => string '536' (length=3)
```

I must get term_id value I can do this with `$var[29]->term_id` but I not know about this element 29, are any solution to get `term_id` ar `29` number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array allways contains only one element, use

```
$tmp=array_values($var);
$term_id=$tmp[0]->term_id;
```

Comment: Not olways, can be more than 1 element

Comment: In this case you need to be clear: Do you want **all** values (use foreach) or the first value (use my answer, it will work)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` on the array (it cycles over all elements in the array giving you key and value):

```
 foreach ($var as $key=>$value) {
     // in this case $key will be 29, $value will be the object.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner for variety:

```
array_pop(array_values($var))->term_id;
```

Comment: This changes the original array! Might not be a problem, but should be noted.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use This code

```
foreach($array as $Key=>$val){

  if(isset($val->term_id)){
     //Your $Key
  }
}
```